# How to map to a different binary for the same program on linux/mac?

Tags: terminal, which

Suppose `which R` returns `/opt/anaconda3/bin/R`, and suppose I have other `R` binaries in other locations, and I want a different R binary to run when I type `R`.

How can I make that happen *without*

- deleting any of the R binaries
- moving any files around

To check that it worked, `R` should run `/some/other/location/R` (and `which R` would return `/some/other/location/R`)

Comment: `which` is a poor choice of command, `type -p` is better. Unix/Linux shells usually use the PATH environment variable to look for programs. So `PATH=/some/other/location:$PATH` will change the search order to find a different R.

Comment: @icarus thanks, I will try `type -p` instead. I thought to change `PATH`, but could that interfere with other programs? for example if I change the order of paths in `PATH`, then when I use other programs, it could load the wrong version of the other program?

Comment: @icarus I'm not saying that's a problem btw, I just want to understand what I'm getting myself in for :-)

Comment: It depends on what else is in /some/other/location - if there is /some/other/location/ls if might be an issue, but if the only binary in /some/other/location is `R` you will be fine.

Comment: Deja vu. Didnt you aksnthis already?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices.

- Change the `PATH` variable, to make it search directories in a different order. This will affect all programs in there directories.
- On Debian, use Debian alternatives (Debian and derivatives). And only useful sometimes.
- Set up a `/opt/bin-override` directory, add it to the head of the `PATH`, and add symlinks of commands that you want to run.
- Add aliases to your `~/.bash_aliases` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` e.g.
   `alias R="/some/other/location/R"`